# Error in building wheel for osqp because "No module named cmake' "

Tags: python, cmake, cvxpy

I'm trying to install the cvxpy package in my virtual environment of PyCharm. I typed `C:\Users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\Scripts>pip install cvxpy`, and got:

```
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-1.2.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting ecos>=2
  Using cached ecos-2.0.10-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Collecting osqp>=0.4.1
  Using cached osqp-0.6.2.post5.tar.gz (226 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (1.23.4)
Collecting scs>=1.1.6
  Using cached scs-3.2.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1.0 in c:\users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\lib\site-packages (from cvxpy) (1.9.3)
Collecting qdldl
  Using cached qdldl-0.1.5.post2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: osqp
  Building wheel for osqp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\<Username>\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\tmptb8bjomi'
       cwd: C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6glakjuq\osqp_f4f485f728cb41eb9bd04d39cf2e5c81
  Complete output (82 lines):
  Disabling LONG
  Remove long integers for numpy compatibility. See:
   - https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5906
   - https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3823
  You can reenable long integers by passing: --osqp --long argument.

  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  running egg_info
  writing src\osqp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\osqp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src\osqp.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src\osqp.egg-info\top_level.txt
  listing git files failed - pretending there aren't any
  reading manifest file 'src\osqp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "C:\Users\<Username>\PycharmProjects\<projectName>\venv\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>     
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
.
.
.
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for osqp
```

Trying `C:\Users\<Username>>pip install cvxpy` does successfuly install cvxpy, but then cvxpy isn't in my virtual environment. I tried uninstalling cmake and then installing cvxpy - didn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled cmake and didn’t work.
cmake version is the latest, ver 3.24.1, obtained from running `pip install cmake`
python version is 3.11.0, pip version is 21.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

Running a macOS Monterey Version 12.4

Faced a similar issue when installing cvxpy in a virtual environment using

`pip install cvxpy`

Tried installing/uninstalling cmake before running the above to no avail. The same error kept appearing

Issue was re-solved and the pip install cvxpy ran smoothly after I ran the following

`brew install cmake`

after noticing the command in the documentation for OSQP https://osqp.org/docs/get_started/sources.html

I am however confused as to why this works and why installing cmake via `pip install cmake` does not?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34027395)

Answer (score 0):

Update: this has been resolved by uninstalling python version 3.11.0 and installing python version 3.10.7. [This page](https://github.com/osqp/osqp/issues/385)  suggested that OSQP developers have validated the build wheels properly for 3.10. So maybe they havn't done that for 3.11 yet.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the zip file for "cvxpy" package from https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy, unzipped the file and went to where the "setup.py" file is, and ran the command "python setup.py install" to successfully install "cvxpy". I am using python 3.11.